# how to get the list of the images from the Application Directory

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I am Developing a Web site and i need to read all the images from the images folder in the
application directory and i have to display all the images on the page can any body tell me how to read all the images from the images folder which is in my application directory.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you an array of the file names in a given path:

```
string[] fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(yourPath);
```

You can then generate URLs for them and use `<img>` tags written out to the response, for example something like ought to get the valid URLs:

```
string relativePath = Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
relativePath = relativePath.Substring(0, relativePath.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
string requestPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath(relativePath));       
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(requestPath);
List<string> imageUrls = new List<string>(fileNames.Length);

foreach(var fileName in fileNames)
{
    imageUrls.Add(Path.Combine(relativePath, Path.GetFileName(fileName))); 
}
```

You could just write out the `<img>` items in the loop. Also, note that a call to `GetFiles` supplying only a path will return all available files so you might want to supply a `searchPattern` argument such as `*.jpg`.

Comment: GetFiles will return the path as below
D:\Running Projects\New VDC\Images\ComputerLab.jpg
when i add this path to img tag then its not displaying the image
<img src="D:\Running Projects\New VDC\Images\ComputerLab.jpg" />

Comment: Yes, you'll need to make the paths relative and prefix the virtual path - I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This could help

https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125318/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052803-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of Mr. Disappointment, you can get a list of all the files using the command specified,

To get the path of the application using Server.MapPath.

Then getting the list of files, you can simply iterate and filter on the extensions you need.